# Jquery file upload with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-file-upload

I have [blueimp jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) working with couple of other form fields in my form. Its working fine in ideal scenarios. But today I got stuck when I tried to incorporate [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) for other 2 fields.

HTML

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div id="saveCancelDashbContainer" class="ui-grid-a cancelSaveBtn">
        <div class="ui-block-a head-div btn-div">
            <button class="cancelBtn" type="reset" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="patientDashbContainer" class="ui-block-b head-div">
            <!--#include virtual="patientDashboardButton.shtml" -->
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c head-div">
             <h1>Add Files</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollManager fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a  mid-div" id="categoryContainer">
                <label for="formCategory">Category</label>
                //Required
                <select id="formCategory" name="formCategory">
                    <option value="pleaseSelect">Select Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" id="fileNameContainer">
                <label for="form_duration">File title</label>
                //Required
                <input name="form_file_name" id="form_file_name" value="" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b full-div" id="notesContainer">
            <label for="chief_complaint">Notes</label>
            <textarea name="form_file_notes" id="form_file_notes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-buttons">
            <label>Select files</label>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" class="start" value="Save" data-inline="true" /> <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade" style="display:none">
            <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <table role="presentation">
            <tbody class="files"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT - File Upload

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '../api/filedocuments/'+localStorage.getItem("PMR_patient_id"),
    submit: function (e, data) {
         if(!$("form").valid())
         {
            return false;
         }else{
            return true;
         }

     }
});
```

JAVASCRIPT - Validation

```
$.validator.addMethod(
"notEqual_select", 
function(value, element, param) {
    return $(element).val() !== "pleaseSelect";
});

$("#fileupload").validate({

//Enabling validation for hidden types
ignore: [],

//Element in which error is shown
errorElement: "p",

//For error element
errorLabelContainer: ".error",

//For error placement
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if($(element).attr("type") !== null && $(element).attr("type") === "hidden"){
        error.insertAfter($(element));
    }
    else{
        error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
    }
},

//Rules of validation
rules: {
    formCategory: {
        notEqual_select: true
    },
    form_file_name: {
        required: true
    }
},

//Validation Messages
messages: {
    formCategory: {
        notEqual_select: "Select category"
    },
    form_file_name: {
        required: "Enter file title"
    }
}});
```

This code is validating required fields when the form is submitted first time but next time when I tried to upload the files even after filling the required fields, it doesn't show any processing at all, files don't upload at all. Let me know if you need more information around it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Where is the jQuery Validate code?  If you want help using this plugin, you'll have to show us your attempt at it.

Comment: Updated code with Jquery validation code and please read the last paragraph again. I have made a little change in the text to make the scenario understandable.

Comment: Having the same problem ... did you found any soltion @AnkurGupta ?

Comment: I haven't got any solution with jquery file upload. So, I have removed jquery fileupload and written my own code for the same, to resolve this issue in my product.